# size test in batch FTP - error 255 - winXP vs win2008R2

Tags: windows, batch-file, ftp, windows-server-2008

I am writing a (i hope) simple script to send files to a ftp server - The script should be ready to run on win server 2008 R2 and win7

First I worked the script out on win7 and my way to test if the put was successful was to make a get. 
I found a little bit strange that the get created a file even if there was no file to transmit. But on win 7 this was not a problem because the "if exist %1 ..(a). else ..(b)." worked as if the file did not exist - strange again (..(a). executed)

And then on win2008R2 I saw that here the test worked as in the other way (..(b). executed)
So I tried to test the file size which worked fine on win7 - but now on win2008R2 I get an error 255 as soon as the ftp part of the script is executed.

Here's the script :

```
@echo off
X:
if not exist %1 exit 2
if not exist control\ md control

rem Connexion.
echo open ...> ftpcmd.dat
echo user ...>> ftpcmd.dat
echo ...>> ftpcmd.dat
echo quote pasv>> ftpcmd.dat
echo binary>> ftpcmd.dat

rem Preparation Upload.
echo put %1>> ftpcmd.dat
echo lcd control>>ftpcmd.dat
echo get %1>> ftpcmd.dat
echo quit>> ftpcmd.dat

rem Execution Upload.
ftp -n -s:ftpcmd.dat

rem Clean up.
if exist ftpcmd.dat del ftpcmd.dat

if exist %1 (
  for /f %%i in (%1) do set /a size=%%~zi
  if %size% equ 0 (
    echo Vide
    set /a errret=3
    del %1
    cd ..
  ) else (
    set /a errret=0
    del %1
    cd ..
    move %1 svg
  )
) else (
  set /a errret=1
  cd ..
)
pause
exit %errret%
```

I'm really not an expert on batchfiles so perhaps I'm doing it in a wrong way.
In any case, after my strange experiences I need some help please !

Comment: It's been a while since I did Windows, but I think you may need double quotes around %1 in case there is a space in the filename, like this `"%1"`

Comment: OK thanks - but no change - my filenames do not contain any space

Comment: I can't see where you `cd control` to check the size of the file you got with `get`? Surely you need to check that?

Comment: again you are right - I just saw this error this morning - problem stays : on win2008r2 this does not work